# how add navigation bullet linked to the slider?

Tags: navigation, slider

hello i have some working code of slider i wondering how add bullet navigation i can add actually, but?in javascript code ul lyst are mixed and that is the problem with bullet don't track slides properly...here is link to code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //set vars for slider size
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({
        width: slideWidth,
        height: slideHeight
    });

    $('#slider ul').css({
        width: sliderUlWidth,
        marginLeft: -slideWidth
    });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
    //move left function (prev)
    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: +slideWidth
        }, 700, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
    //move right function (next)
    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: -slideWidth
        }, 700, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
    // call functions on click 
    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);
 html {
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    color: #2a2a2a;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
h1 {
    color: #00AAE1;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #aaaaaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px#aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #aaaaaa;
}
#slider ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 906px;
    height: 550px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev, a.control_next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    padding: 4% 3%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #4AC8E9;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
a.control_next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.slider_option {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.footer {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<htmL>
<head>
        <title>SME's</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="presStyle.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
<h1><span style="color: #333;">Broadband</span></h1>

        <div id="slider"> <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
 <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>

            <ul>
                <li>slide1</li>
                <li>slide2</li>
                <li>slide3</li>
                <li class="final">slide4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
        <script src="sliderJQ.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: bullets must be clickable :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m61qfck1/2/ i need somthing simular like this